# How to use expander to update the data in atk4 grid?

Tags: atk4

Let's say I created a model "product" with a few fields such as "name", "price","tax","shipping" etc.

At first I just want to show name and price in the grid:

```
$g = $this->add('MVCGrid')
$g -> setModel('product', array('name','price'));
```

Then I would like to add a column of expander button called "sold" to update the "tax" and "shipping" for that product:

```
$g -> addColumn('expander','sold');
```

In the sold.php file, I put:

```
$f = $this -> add('MVCForm');
$f -> setModel('product',array('tax','shipping'));
$f -> addSubmit()-> setLabel('Update');
```

My question is how to get the id of the product I am trying to update in the expander page? i.e. what kind of code should I put in the

```
if($f->isSubmitted()){

}
```

in order to update the tax and shipping of the product which I clicked the "sold" expander button on?

---

BTW: is there any way that I can close the expander after I hit the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

Expander passes the id through several GET variables:

- id
- tablename_id (calculated based on model->entity_code

Using 'id' is handy, but the second method is handier if you are doing nesting expanders. Don't forget to use stickyGET().

Comment: `var_dump($_GET)`; I think it should be `$_GET['product_id']`

Comment: Yes, I know the 'tablename' means the 'entity_code' defined in the model so I did try $_GET['product_id'] but it returns NULL. don't know why. Anyway, the $_GET['id'] works now after adding the stickyGET(), I just didn't know when to use the trick stickyGET()...Thanks

Comment: BTW: is there any way that I can close the expander after I hit the submit button?